# SSRS IIF Date evaluation

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have the following code

```
=IIf(Fields!Freeze.Value, Fields!effectivedate.Value, IIF(Month(Fields!effectivedate.Value) <> Month(Now()), Format(Now(), “MM/dd/yyyy”) , Fields!effectivedate.Value))
```

A. In the first IIF statement I check to see if the Fields!Freeze.Value is true, if its true then It displays Fields!effectivedate.Value  (IIf(Fields!Freeze.Value, Fields!effectivedate.Value)

B. In the second IIF statemenet I check if the Fields!effectivedate.Value is the current month, If it is the current month then it displays Fields!effectivedate.Value, If it is not the current month then it displays the current date.

I would like assistance on the following.

In the first IIF statement ,>>> `IIf(Fields!Freeze.Value, Fields!effectivedate.Value,`
I want to evaluate a new value  Fields!FreezeDate.value

1. If the Fields!Freeze.Value = true then  check to see if the Fields!effectivedate.Value is 30 days or more less than Fields!FreezeDate.value. 
   A.  If its 29 days or less than Fields!FreezeDate.value then display Fields!effectivedate.Value
   B.  If its 30 days or more less than the Fields!FreezeDate.value then display the Fields!FreezeDate.value

Example 1

```
 Fields!FreezeDate.value  = '12/30/2012'
 Fields!effectivedate.Value = '11/15/2010'


 then Display the Fields!FreezeDate.value
```

Example 2

```
 Fields!FreezeDate.value  = '12/30/2012'
 Fields!effectivedate.Value = '12/15/2010'


 then Display the Fields!effectivedate.Value
```

How would I write this in SSRS code?

Please ask for further clarification if i have failed to explain something properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the requirement, you'll need to add another IIf() section which checks the difference in days between the two dates, then displays effectiveDate if the difference is < 30 days:

```
=IIf
(
  Fields!Freeze.Value
  , IIF
  (
    DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Fields!effectiveDate.Value, Fields!FreezeDate.Value) < 30
    , Fields!effectiveDate.Value
    , Fields!FreezeDate.Value
  )
  , IIF
  (
    Month(Fields!effectivedate.Value) <> Month(Now())
    , Format(Now(), “MM/dd/yyyy”)
    , Fields!effectivedate.Value
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the thing you're missing is knowledge of the `DATEDIFF` function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337092%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

```
IIF(
  DATEDIFF(DAY, Fields!FreezeDate.Value, Fields!effectiveDate.Value) => 30,
  Fields!FreezeDate.Value, 
  Fields!effectiveDate.Value )
```

Above, we're using `DATEDIFF`.

First parameter is the Time measurement we want to measure differences between.  DAY.

Example:-

`DATEDIFF(DAY, '2013-01-01', '2013-01-15')` should yield 14.

Tying it all up, we're calculating the day difference between `FreezeDate` and `effectiveDate`.  When that value is over 30, display the `effectiveDate`.  Otherwise, display `FreezeDate`.

You may need to play around to get the desired result.  Your English description of your logic was not great.  Did the best I could under the circumstances.