# SQL DateTime >= and <= not behaving as it should

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to add a date range filter to a SQL query in the form of:

```
SELECT * FROM Database
WHERE
(CreatedOn >= '2015-01-14' AND
CreatedOn <= '2015-01-14')
```

Which means I would like to return all rows that match for the 14/01/2015 from the CreatedOn field.

This comes back with 0 rows.

If I change the `CreatedOn <= '2015-01-14'` to `CreatedOn <= '2015-01-15'` it does however fix it but I don't want the user to do that, it should work if selecting the same date for both.

How to fix this?

Comment: It will return all records with CreatedOn='2015-01-14'.

Comment: to be very specific convert the value to Datetime and do the comparison

Comment: what is the type of the `CreatedOn` column does it also save the time part that may be the reason you are not getting result

Comment: @sd_dracula you can go with the answer given by @Ajay2707 as it takes care of time part if you want range then user `BETWEEN` for that

Comment: You can use datediff: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189794%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx

Comment: For ssrs point of view date compare:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197057/ssrs-iif-date-evaluation

Comment: I've missed `it should work if selecting the same date for both`.
Please check my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very general thing we do, while compare date-time field with only date or string date. It might be that you get result, the reason is formatting and the time.

What you should, when you compare, discard the time portion and give same date format to both side.

```
SELECT * FROM Database
WHERE cast( CreatedOn as date)  >= '2015-01-20'
and cast( CreatedOn as date)  <= '2015-01-20'

or 

SELECT * FROM Database
WHERE cast( CreatedOn as date)  between ('2015-01-20' and '2015-01-20')
```

**Updated :- for ssrs date compare**

[SSRS IIF Date evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197057/ssrs-iif-date-evaluation)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/87c519e2-93cd-4bea-85ed-98b2dc885b78/how-will-i-compare-two-dates-in-ssrs-2005?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Can you update your answer as OP wants it between the range of date

Comment: This works but it must be in the form of a range as I need both fields in a SSRS report.

Comment: What do you mean by range it will give you the all records between 2 date ranges and it will work in SSRS

Comment: The first one seems to be working as fine. Looks like needed to convert to date.

Answer (score 0):

This will not work if there is milliseconds

```
SELECT * FROM Database
WHERE
(CreatedOn >= '2015-01-14 00:00:00' AND
CreatedOn <= '2015-01-14 23:59:59')
```

This will work

```
SELECT * FROM Database
WHERE cast( CreatedOn as date)  >= '2015-01-14')
and cast( CreatedOn as date)  <= '2015-01-14')
```

But you can simply rewrite as

```
SELECT * FROM Database
WHERE cast( CreatedOn as date)  = '2015-01-14'
```

But this applies function to an argument and so if you have indexes on Date column `SQL SERVER` will not use those indexes. You can read about Search Arguments(SARG).

Instead try the following

```
SELECT * FROM Database
WHERE
CreatedOn >= '2015-01-14' AND
CreatedOn < DATEADD(dd, 1, '2015-01-14')
```

And you can simply replace '2015-01-14' with required parameter here like

```
SELECT * FROM Database
WHERE
CreatedOn >= @Dt1 AND
CreatedOn < DATEADD(dd, 1, @Dt2)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a query like this

`SELECT * FROM Database WHERE CreatedOn between T1 and T2`

Comment: Again, same result. No rows if both values are same date but works if the second one is + 1 day

Comment: just read you comment to find that the column is datetime datatype. So Ajay2707 has posted a query which should work for you.